# Background image 50% opacity when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Backstretch jQuery plugin, and want to make the background darker when scrolling down.

This is what i made so far.
Body background-color dark
Background-image to have opacity 0.4 when scrolling down 800px.

What i have left is to make the fade effect go slow. Right now it goes from opacity 1 to 0.4 really fast.

Here is my code

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 800) {
        $('.backstretch').css("opacity", 0.4).fadeIn("slow");;
    }
    else{
        $('.backstretch').css("opacity", 1).fadeIn("slow") ;
    }
});
```

Could anyone please help me fade it in really slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace your code with

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 800) {
        $('.backstretch').css("opacity", 0.4).fadeIn("5000");;
    }
    else{
        $('.backstretch').css("opacity", 1).fadeIn("5000") ;
    }
});
```

where "5000" represents the time of the animation in milliseconds.

Comment: Hey thanks @angelo for help!
In the end i did change some of the code and it looks like this now


    $(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1 && $(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
    $(".backstretch").animate({opacity: 0.2}, "1000");
            return;
        } 
        $(".backstretch").animate({opacity: 1}, "1000").stop( true, true );

    });